# How to solve logout error when using Django-Jazzmin?

Tags: python, css, django, admin

I have built a Django project recently, and while searching for methods to customize the admin panel, I found `Django-Jazzmin`. It is working and cool and all that, but I have one single problem with it, whenever I try to logout from the admin page, it returns the error `405`, a.k.a `"method not allowed"`. I am working with the `Django 5.0.2` framework.

Did someone find the solution for this problem?

I tried to go to `"my-virtual_env\Lib\site-packages\jazzmin\templates\admin\base.html"`
and modify the logout block to :

```html
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'admin:logout' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fas fa-users mr-2"></i> {% trans 'Log out' %}
        </button>
    </form>
```

but it didn't help!

Comment: Can you check that template is indeed updated? Open dev tools in your browser, and check that button is actually `button`, not `a` tag

Comment: Also, have you considered using Django 4.2 until jazzmin resolves issue?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the logout error when using Django-Jazzmin, you can modify the logout link in the admin template to use a form submission instead of a simple hyperlink. This is a common issue with Django admin when using custom templates or plugins like Django-Jazzmin.

Follow these steps:

1. Navigate to the template file where the Django-Jazzmin admin interface is being customized. This is usually located at `/rootProject/templates/admin/base.html`.
2. Locate the logout link in the template. It may look something like this:

```html
<a href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}" class="dropdown-item">
    <i class="fas fa-users mr-2"></i> {% trans 'Log out' %}
</a>
```

3. Replace the above code with a form submission:

```html
<form action="{% url 'admin:logout' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item">
        <i class="fas fa-users mr-2"></i> {% trans 'Log out' %}
    </button>
</form>
```

4. Save the changes to the `base.html` file.

By replacing the logout link with a form submission, you ensure that the logout operation is performed via a POST request, which is the expected method for sensitive operations like logging out. This should resolve the 405 error you're encountering when trying to log out from the admin page.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have major dependencies with Django 4.2 or above, try downgrading the Django version to 4.1, it will work. There is a PR already raised in the package author's repository. This problem is yet to be merged.

Here is the PR: https://github.com/farridav/django-jazzmin/pull/523